# What popular webservers have support for HTML5 WebSocket?

Tags: html, webserver, websocket

I would like to experiment with HTML5 WebSockets, and I am looking for a mature webserver with support for websockets. Is there a list of webservers that support websockets per default? **What popular webservers has support for websockets out of the box?** The server programming language doesn't matter, I know Java, PHP, Erlang, Python and more... I just want to do some small experiments.

I have looked at a few that doesn't support websockets (yet), i.e. Nginx, Apache and Mochiweb.

Comment: For those who're using Django, Channels is the answer. According to the community, Channels will be officially released in Django 1.10

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nowadays [node.js](http://nodejs.org/), especially in conjuction with the [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) library, is a popular platform for WebSocket experiments. It's not a traditional "webserver" like Apache/nginx but it certainly offers a "server programming language" that's super easy to set up for small experiments and is possible to deploy in production too.

Answer (score 9):

You can find a mod_websocket module for lighttpd [here](http://github.com/nori0428/mod_websocket). I've tested it with lighttpd 1.4.26.

When building mod_websocket, be sure to specify the correct websocket protocol version you want to use (version -75 or -76). Starting with WebKit nightly build r59903 and Chrome 6.0.414.0 (r47952) only protocol version -76 is supported.

Comment: Unfortunately, mod_websocket does not work with the latest versions of lighttpd.

Answer (score 6):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Sockets#Server_Implementations

I tested netty. It seems to work, but I need to play with it a little more to be sure if it's good solution.

Comment: The link you provided doesn't contain the section but the German page does: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets#Server-Implementierungen

Comment: thanks for this comment. I hate overzealous admins on wikipedia. English version can be found in edit history: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=WebSockets&oldid=367302004

Answer (score 5):

[Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) (a Java servletcontainer) supports HTML5 websockets since version 7.0.1. You can find several information and blogs about it [here](http://www.google.com/search?q=jetty+websocket).

Answer (score 4):

I just tried out [tornado web server](http://www.tornadoweb.org) and I'm really satisfied. You will easily get up and running in no time.

Answer (score 2):

[Apache Tomcat 7](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/index.html) and later versions [support](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html) [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).