# Is it possible to use port 80 for both HTTP and web socket traffic?

Tags: apache, http, sockets, websocket

1. I'm building a site that uses web sockets (technically Flash sockets) in order to provide real-time communication.
2. I want to be able to support people behind corporate/academic firewalls that block everything except port 80
3. I'd like to be able to run the site off of a single machine

Previously, I've been using Apache for HTTP serving combined with some python listening on a high-numbered socket for the websocket stuff, but that obviously won't work here.

I can always move the websocket stuff to a separate server, but I'd like to avoid paying for a second VPS (and have to talk to the database over the network instead of locally). Is there a good way to do this (nodejs, nginx, ..?), or is it not worth the headache?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What popular webservers have support for HTML5 WebSocket?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924991/what-popular-webservers-have-support-for-html5-websocket)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- http://code.google.com/p/pywebsocket/
- [What popular webservers have support for HTML5 WebSocket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924991/what-popular-webservers-have-support-for-html5-websocket)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/201825/how-would-i-configure-a-websocket-server-to-run-alongside-a-webserver

Another possibility is to use mod_proxy in apache to redirect the requests to a websocket server.

Comment: Note that **pywebsocket** is not meant for production, rather only for testing (client implementation) - at which it is really good though btw.

Answer (score 16):

YES, by using [node.js](http://nodejs.org/). [Express](http://expressjs.com/) or [connect](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/) for the HTTP file serving and [socket.io](http://socket.io/) for the WebSocket stuff.

Example:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express.createServer(); 

app.get('/', function(req, res){ 
    res.redirect("/index.html");
}); 

app.configure(function(){
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.listen(80); 

var io = require('socket.io'); 
var socket = io.listen(app); 
socket.on('connection', function(client){ 
  client.on('message', function(){...});
})
```

Comment: Could you please explain what it does?

Answer (score 5):

Of course you can do this.

Firstly you have to check your Apache version. You should have 2.4+ version. I will show you command for my server on Ubuntu 14.4.

Secondly, turn on necessary apache modules:

```
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
a2enmod proxy_wstunnel
```

Open conf of your domain, in my case that was a path to file:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/myDomain.pl.conf
```

Next, append this code

```
<VirtualHost>

.
.
.

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=polling
RewriteRule /(.*)$ http://localhost:3001/$1 [P]

ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass /socket.io ws://localhost:3001/socket.io
ProxyPassReverse /socket.io ws://localhost:3001/socket.io

ProxyPass        /socket.io http://localhost:3001/socket.io
ProxyPassReverse /socket.io http://localhost:3001/socket.io
</VirtualHost>
```

Finaly restart your apache

```
service apache2 restart
```

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks, this works great. However what is the purpose of the RewriteCond and RewriteRule? It seems to work fine without those.

Comment: And explanation of why each line is required, even 5 years later, would still be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

For secure websocket, all I needed to do was to add these three lines to my https virthualhost :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    [...https config...]

    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyPass "/web_socket"  "wss://localhost:7300/web_socket"
    ProxyPassReverse "/web_socket"  "wss://localhost:7300/web_socket"

</VirtualHost>
```

And enable the mod_proxy_wstunnel apache module (I'm running apache 2.4.10) :

```
a2enmod proxy_wstunnel
```

Answer (score 0):

GlassFish (and grizzly) support both HTTP and websockets traffic on the same port if a java server is an option.

Answer (score -5):

The short answer is no, because you can only have one process listening on one port.  You could try using port 443, since that is not going to be blocked either, as long as you also do not use https.

Comment: -1: First of all multiple process **can** listen on the same port in some cases (forking: for examples Apache spawns a process per request). Secondly serving WebSockets can be done within one process, i.e. a client opens TCP and depending on whether he sends (standard) HTTP or WebSocket it handles it differently.

Comment: he specified apache and python.  I was only trying to answer that, if your using apache and python, I do not know of a way to have both of those processes listening on the same port at the same time.

Comment: @freakish Technically multiple processes are **not** listening on the same port. One process is listening and when it receives something it handles that processes forks to handle the request and goes back to listening. In short, only one process is ever listening. Everything else you've said is completely correct.