# cross domain configuration issues using nginx, sails and upstart

Tags: angularjs, nginx, sails.js, upstart, sails.io.js

I'm having cross domain configuration issues using nginx and sails. The problem is that 
if I get the socket to connect properly via `http://domain-server.com/socket.io/` 
then the RESTful request will fail. If RESTful works the socket will not.

**Setup**

Client `http://domain.com`

Server `http://server-domain.com`

Client is an angular application using `"sails.io.js": "0.10.3"` and this config `io.sails.url = 'http://domain-server.com';`.

Server is a sails application with both RESTful request and socket features.

**Sails CORS config**

```
module.exports.cors = {
    allRoutes: true,
    origin: 'http://domain.com',
    credentials: true,
    methods: 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD',
    headers: 'content-type,Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
};
```

**Sails socket config**

```
module.exports.socket {
    onConnect: function() {},
    onDisconnect: function() {},
    authorization: false,
    'backwardsCompatibilityFor0.9SocketClients': false,
    grant3rdPartyCookie: true,
    origins: 'http://domain.com'
};
```

**nginx config**

Commented out are what I've fiddled with in the nginx configuration without much success (also tried the client address instead of *).

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name domain-server.com;
#add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    location / {
#       add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:1337;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
#        proxy_set_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
}
```

**angularjs service method making the RESTful calls**

```
function query(path, attributes) {

    return $http({
        url: domain + path,
        params: attributes,
        method: "GET",
        widthCredentials: true
    });
}
```

**In the angular config function**

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
```

It is the current configuration and here are the results I am experiencing.

**Browser console output**

`Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://domain-server.com/__getcookie".` - Good

`|>

  \___/   sails.io.js:200
 io.socket connected successfully.` - Good

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://domain-server.com/login?password=test&username=test. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://domain.com' is therefore not allowed access.` - Not good

**UPDATE**

It seems like everything works wonder if I start sails directly using `sails lift` or `node app.js` yet when starting it using the upstart script in a `.conf` file the cross domain issue occurs.

**upstart script**

```
#!upstart
description "demo"
author "gillesc"

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on shutdown

respawn
respawn limit 5 60

script
  exec /usr/bin/node /var/www/apps/domain-server.com/app.js > /var/www/apps/domain-server.com/server.log 2>&1
end script
```

Comment: Where is this hosted?  Certain cloud hosts (like OpenStack) seem to block CORS headers from being sent.

Comment: I can get the CORS to work fine for RESTful, it just when they do the socket.io side of thing no longer work. Sounds like there is a conflict somewhere.

Comment: What do you get if you navigate to `http://domain-server.com/login?password=test&username=test` in the browser? Is it an nginx error page? Are you reverse proxying requests properly from nginx to the sails application? Or are they on different ports?

Comment: @david I'm getting `Not Found`, from nginx I think as the 404 sails view is just the string `404`.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like you're serving the sails app and the websocket from the same port. Either switch the websocket over to a different port or decide which urls should go to which and set up nginx.

Comment: Theoretically you should be able to run socket.io and a webserver on the same port: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5969772/867294, but maybe nginx doesn't like it. Can you visit: `http://localhost:1337/login?password=test&username=test` directly?  do you still get the 404 ? Are any CORS headers present ? If rest is working, I don't think you should try to modify any CORS headers from nginx

Comment: Removing the socket configuration make that works all the time. For the REST calls I noticed something weird, if I start the application using `sails lift` or even `node app.js` manually it works perfectly. If I use `start server-name` the cross domain issue occur. I'll update my question with the upstart script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to the top of your Sails app's **app.js** file:

```
process.chdir(__dirname);
```

The `not found` you're seeing is likely the default Express 404 message.  If you try to lift a Sails app outside of its own directory, the API files (e.g. controllers) won't get loaded properly.  The `process.chdir` was added to the default **app.js** at some point to prevent this problem, but it looks like there was a regression somewhere along the way.