# COMET realization for Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, node.js, websocket, comet

I have a project, where i have to always keep connection (uploading comments, and so on...).
We tried use [WebSocket module](http://www.drupal.org/project/websockets), but it's version work very unstable (i could not run test apps, and i get something strange with web-socket php server). I wrote some quistions about it to author, but he didn't answer to me.

Then i'd download [node.js module](http://drupal.org/project/nodejs), and now i'm trying to setup it.. but i don't know is it better variant?
Send packet to server evry 2 second's with just JavaScript - is bad idea)

Did somebody already decide this question, or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related questions (but ultimately you are going to struggle with PHP since it doesn't work well with maintaining concurrent connections):

- [websocket feature over apache based service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803856/websocket-feature-over-apache-based-service/8811808)
- [websockets apache server compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804313/websockets-apache-server-compatibility/8809793)
- [Recommend Comet implementation with Web Sockets and PHP support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617168/recommend-comet-implementation-with-web-sockets-and-php-support/8619243)
- [How to implement a real fast web chat with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176937/how-to-implement-a-real-fast-web-chat-with-php/8213175)
- [How to implement Comet [with PHP]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118828/how-to-implement-comet/8167229#8167229)